# WKWebview Open target=“_blank” link in Default Browser on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I'm trying to make WKWebview Open external links (target=_blank) in Default Browser on macOS using Swift Code for Xcode. This code is only for downloading zip or nzb link files and does not work:

#### Attempt

```
func webView(webView: WebView!, decidePolicyForNavigationAction actionInformation: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, request: NSURLRequest!, frame: WebFrame!, decisionListener listener: WebPolicyDecisionListener!) {
    let url = request.URL!.absoluteString
    if url.hasSuffix(".zip") || url.hasSuffix(".nzb") {
        listener.ignore()
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(request.URL!)
    } else {
        listener.use()
    }
}
```

The code is not working for the Webview App on macosx 10.14 and webview, and WebPolicyDecisionListener was deprecated for 10.14.

I want WKWebview to open the external links (target=_blank) using Swift.

Comment: Is `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(request.URL!)` executed at runtime?

Comment: no but the  NSWorkspace.shared.open(request.url!)  will executed

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the `webView.uiDelegate = ...` to and instance of `WKUIDelegate` then handle `createWebViewWith:for:windowFeatures:` for example;

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url, navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        let shared = UIApplication.shared
        if shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            shared.open(url, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any](), completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: The example is iOS specific, it can easily be adapted to macOS.